# What can I do to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer, context

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4150325/the-integral-frac12-int-0-infty-xn-operatornamesechx-mathrm-dx) self-answered question has $5$ downvotes . Metamorphy commented that 'Still the question should have a context and not just a problem statement' after which I added an attempt. After discussion with Paramanand Singh here in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124653/discussion-between-nikhil-kumar-singh-and-paramanand-singh), I edited the question and added the link which helped me in finding the solution,i.e, the context. I generated this question on my own while solving another question, which I mentioned in the question. Now, it didn't appeal to me why are the downvotes coming? Is it because that they don't find this question interesting? According to the Stack overflow blog [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.131911951.1250830019.1618675110-2119719802.1618675110), it is encouraged to ask and answer your own questions. But that does not seem to be the case here. In the constructive feedback room, I was told that self-answered questions have to meet high-quality standards. This means, that my question was low-quality. But how? Could I know the reason?

> How could I improve so that it may not attract downvotes?

Comment: In my opinion the context you added was a big improvement.

Comment: I hope your question stays open. The community is always willing to help people who are sincerely putting effort for any kind of improvement.

Comment: By now it has left the close queue: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/1604052

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to improve the question.  You did a great job!

Comment: As of this writing, the question is closed, but has two votes toward reopening.

Comment: You don't need to update this question every time the downvote count changes.  We are all capable of clicking on the link to see it ourselves :)